# Remove package with yum but leave libraries in place?

Tags: yum, rpm, gcc, libraries

During setup on a specific set of servers, I need `gcc-c++` installed to compile some of the software I am setting up.  After install is complete I need to remove the compiler for security reasons.  However, the libraries that `gcc-c++` installs need to remain in place.

I can see the `.so` and `.a` files in the output of `repoquery --list gcc-c++`.

I could just copy those specific libraries to `/tmp`, run `yum remove gcc-c++`, and then move the libraries back into place.

Is there an already created solution to this?  e.g. is there an option that `yum` or `rpm` has that would allow me to leave specific files from the package in place?

If no option in `yum` or `rpm`, is there any preferable way of doing it than my suggestion of copying to `/tmp` and moving them back afterward??

Comment: `.a` is never needed at runtime, and in `gcc-c++` *for CentOS6* (admittedly not the latest) the only `.so` I have is `libstdc++`. Runtime should not need that copy of libstdc++, but rather use the 'runtime' one installed by *package* `libstdc++` in `/usr/lib[64]`

Comment: This *is* on RHEL 6, so that is helpful!  Do you have a reference for the statement that packages should only need the `/usr/lib` copy of the `libstdc++`?  (That reference could be exactly what I need to show the people I'm working with.)

Comment: No reference. Since "dynamic" (runtime) libs started being used, I think in OS/360 ca 1965, they have almost always been usable without compiletime tools so I just expect it. But it's easy to demo: just `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld; ldd helloworld` and you see it's using `/usr/lib[64]` and not `/usr/lib/gcc/$config/$ver/`. Copy the executable to a machine (perhaps VM) with gcc and -devel NOT installed, and it works (libstdc++ runtime, like glibc for C, is in the base install).